# Put Observer Event on Recurring Profile Suspend

Tags: php, magento

I have created a custom Module,In which i am Selling Recurring Product, if Customer buy and Recurring product then after placing Order Successfully,i am making some changes in Custom database table now i want if customer suspend that recurring profile from his/her id then my custom module database table must be updated according to that. is there any event observer that i can but on suspend button ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever event name you want in Magento. Don't know what do you mean by "suspending recurring profile" but when this happens you can fire/dispatch your custom event, for example:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('stop_recurring_orders_save_after', array(
                'some_id'             => &$someId,
                'other_fields'            => &$otherFields,
            ));
```

You can find how to handle events in Magento here on SO. 
Shortly in `config.xml` you need something like:

```
<config>
    <global>
        <events>
            <stop_recurring_orders_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <mycustomextension>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>mycustomextension/observer</class>
                        <method>stopRecurringOrders</method>
                    </mycustomextension>
                </observers>
            </stop_recurring_orders_save_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

And an observer class with the appropriate method (e.g. `stopRecurringOrders`):

```
class Mycustomextension_Model_Observer {
    public function stopRecurringOrders($event) {
        $id = $event->getSomeId();

        // update your custom table etc.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the Events in Magento are available at
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/magento_events
You can check them and select which suits your requirement....